# Movie Distortion Node in compositor does not respect optical shift values from Movie-Clip-Editor?

Tags: compositing-nodes, camera, tracking, movie-clip-editor

I am stuck in quite a situation.
I had to track a footage shot with a **fisheye lens @ 8mm** ( 8-15 f/4 canon fisheye ) attached to a red-epic camera.
The footage also has its **optical centre shifted** quite a bit in Y and slightly in X. This with the amount of distortion on the footage made me think that the footage would be untrackable.

It is a shot of a helicopter flyover a landscape for a ride film. 
There is no lens chart shot for this.

However to my surprise, blender solved the camera nicely. It also **calculated the focal, distortion( polynomial with k1 and k2 ), optical centre values** (movie clip > properties bar > camera Panel> ).

blender gave a **descent solve with the 3d locators almost sticking**.
The undistorted footage looks correct when I generate the undistorted proxies. The locators stick to this undistorted footage.
However, when I used **the movie distortion node in the compositor** set to undistort, the distortion comes out **different compared to undistorted proxy** that blender generated. I think that it is **not considering the shift in the optical centre?**

How Can I solve this issue? 
I **tried to use the translate as well as transform nodes** before attaching the movie clip to distort node in the compositor, but got no luck.

Unfortunately I cannot share the screenshot images as I am in office and NDAs.

Here are the camera values in MovieClipEditor.
Footage size : 4752x3160 , 1360 frames
Camera Sensor Width : 30.00
Optical centre : x = 2401.30, y = 2241.951
Focal length : 14.35
Distortion values : k1 = -.231, k2 = .029, k3 = 0.0
Solve error = 9.33 ( Believe me, it good for the footage. I plan to refine it further. )

3d View camera values : 
under camera > lens > shift X = -.005, shift Y = -.139
focal : 14.35

Thank you for reading this long post and any help/ advice.

Comment: Are the scene frame dimensions the same as those of the original frame? Please post an image of your node setup

Comment: 9.33 pixels is still to high for a solve error...

Answer (score 1):

thanks for the reply :)

I actually did manage to get the distortion working properly. :) 
My mistake was that I had hit the "centre" button( Movie Clip Editor > Properties panel > camera > centre ) after solving and that was throwing the undistort node off in the compositor.

Setting the correct values again in the "centre" panel fixed it.

I cannot post the images here as "uploading" is blocked in  my office due to security reasons.

The high error values I will solve later in another proprietery software @my office.  Its awesome.

Thanks, 
Jayraj